# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070064

Tags: android, android-tablayout

**Hi, I'm getting this exception,Not found any solution.** Any Advice ?

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.developerfyk.winnerinno, PID: 26127
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developerfyk.winnerinno/com.example.developerfyk.winnerinno.Activity.HomeActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f070064
>
> ```
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
> ```
>
> ## 0x7f070064
>
> ```
>                   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>                   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(TabLayout.java:1388)
>                   at com.example.developerfyk.winnerinno.Activity.HomeActivity.setupTabIcons(HomeActivity.java:113)
>                   at com.example.developerfyk.winnerinno.Activity.HomeActivity.initView(HomeActivity.java:65)
>                   at com.example.developerfyk.winnerinno.Activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:71)
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
> ```
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8629', transport:
>   'socket'

**my code is :**

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

    /**
     * Activity class name holder variable
     */
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Variables
     */
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_home;
    }

    @Override
    protected Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initView() {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        setupTabIcons();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initView();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        JZVideoPlayer.releaseAllVideos();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       JZVideoPlayer.releaseAllVideos();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(JZVideoPlayer.backPress()){
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        int[] tabIcons = {
                R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
                R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts,
                R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite
        };

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new JoinFragment(),"join");
        adapter.addFrag(new RateFragment(),"rate");
        adapter.addFrag(new WinnerFragment(),"winner");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment,String title){
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            // return null to display only the icon
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you have declared your activity in manifest

Answer (score 0):

This is probably (without knowing your BaseActivity class) because you didn't add the layout with `setContentView()` in your activity `onCreate()`. Where:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  initView();
}

@Override
protected void initView() {
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ...
}
```

You must add the layout first with something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout. activity_home);
  initView();
}
```